# How can I reference the store path of a Nix package?

Tags: nix

I'd like to add functionality relating to the `awscli` command completion.

In my particular case I need to source the script from `/nix/store/hvx7xqvjz7r08nsb9kssh1d9s302v3sp-awscli-1.16.106/share/zsh/site-functions/aws_zsh_completer.sh`.

How can I get the store path (`/nix/store/hvx7xqvjz7r08nsb9kssh1d9s302v3sp-awscli-1.16.106`) for a package (`awscli`)? As I don't think hardcoding this reference is ideal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `configuration.nix` to create a symlink in `/etc` that points to the file you want to source. Then you simply source said symlink. For example, something like this...

**configuration.nix**

```
environment.etc."zsh/zshrc".source = "${pkgs.awscli}/share/zsh/site-functions/aws_zsh_completer.sh";
```

...would create the symbolic link `/etc/zsh/zshrc` which would point to `/nix/store/hvx7xqvjz7r08nsb9kssh1d9s302v3sp-awscli-1.16.106/share/zsh/site-functions/aws_zsh_completer.sh`

Since this is done through `configuration.nix`, the symbolic link will get updated to the correct path each time you build the system.

Then, you can source `/etc/zsh/zshrc` in your `~.zshrc`.

Answer (score 4):

Through `nix-locate` , install it then update the database with `nix-index`:

```
nix-locate "PATTERN"
```

Comment: https://github.com/bennofs/nix-index#nix-index-

Answer (score 2):

You could use `nix eval --raw` to print the store path of a package. For your example:

```
ls $(nix eval --raw nixpkgs.awscli)/share/zsh/site-functions/aws_zsh_completer.sh
```

This file will only exist if the package is already in your local nix store.

⚠️ *Update in June 2022 with nix 2.8.0*

This command no longer works as-is. I tried to updated it and came up with this:

```
ls $(nix --extra-experimental-features nix-command --extra-experimental-features flakes eval -f '<nixpkgs>' --raw 'awscli')/share/zsh/site-functions/aws_zsh_completer.sh
```

For what it's worth, if you're trying to set up your shell initialization to reference nix packages, the workaround I'm using at the moment is to do this:

```
export NIX_PROFILE_ROOT=${NIX_PROFILES[(w)2]}
maybesource () {
    [[ -r $1 ]] && . $1
}
```

And then reference packages via the nix profile:

```
maybesource $NIX_PROFILE_ROOT/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this has changed since this answer was posted, but for me I need to use eg `nix eval --raw nixpkgs#awscli` - note the hash instead of a period.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking to do this in Bash with newer versions of Nix, use `nix eval -f '<nixpkgs>' --raw PACKAGE`.

For example, `nix eval -f '<nixpkgs>' --raw firefox` or `nix eval -f '<nixpkgs>' --raw xorg.libX11`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different problem, but this is in the top DDG results for `nix store reference` so I'll leave this here. My problem wasn't so much that I needed to reference a specific file from another package in my package, I just needed my package to have a rundep (`buildInputs`) on particular store paths so I could install it to my profile and they wouldn't be GC'd. (I was sick of constantly re-downloading paths when using `nix-shell`, and while `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.stdenv` worked, `nix-env -iA nixpkgs.bash` is apparently a different copy.)

Just putting the store paths into a text file in `$out` doesn't work, they need to be passed through `builtins.storePath` first:

```
writeTextDir "share/nix-shell-nogc" (builtins.concatStringsSep "\n" (builtins.map builtins.storePath [
    "/nix/store/2r4gr92p49kpx48s0hxxxv04cqbx4d6c-bash-interactive-5.1-p16-dev"
    "/nix/store/76yin93c7c0jv29kq2hr39d5rzd0v6dg-bash-interactive-5.1-p16-doc"
    "/nix/store/d2m4s6bm6gxpwd22pv20cbhl3ikbhhpb-bash-interactive-5.1-p16-man"
    "/nix/store/p5fqinp9r82fr92rncwxmhd8nsk3igjy-bash-interactive-5.1-p16-info"
]))
```

Or alternatively, use path literals (doesn't build unless the paths exist, while the above method downloads them during build if necessary):

```
writeTextDir "share/nix-shell-nogc" ''
    ${/nix/store/2r4gr92p49kpx48s0hxxxv04cqbx4d6c-bash-interactive-5.1-p16-dev}
    ${/nix/store/76yin93c7c0jv29kq2hr39d5rzd0v6dg-bash-interactive-5.1-p16-doc}
    ${/nix/store/d2m4s6bm6gxpwd22pv20cbhl3ikbhhpb-bash-interactive-5.1-p16-man}
    ${/nix/store/p5fqinp9r82fr92rncwxmhd8nsk3igjy-bash-interactive-5.1-p16-info}
'';
```

I don't like that I had to hardcode the paths, but it gets the job done.